# Printing Output Iterating Over DF Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have no idea what I'm doing, but the goal of this code is to scrape all link hrefs from several pages (did not include pagination code on purpose) and store them in pandas DF. I would like to print all of the rows from df2 once the loop has finished. the "for i in range(0,10)" only runs the loop 10 and appends the links 10 times.

How do I code it so that it continue appending all the links (not limited to 10)? Sorry for being a newbie.

```
for linkurl in linkcontainer:
    link = linkurl.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[2]/div/div/span/a').get_attribute("href")

    df_links = pd.DataFrame([[link]], columns=['link'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(0,10):
        df2 = df2.append(df_links)

/// loop breaks here when it paginates through all pages ///

print(df2.link.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is over-writing your dataframe with every loop, you need to store it to some sort of list or dictionary, for example :

```
links = []
    for linkurl in linkcontainer:
        link = linkurl.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[2]/div/div/span/a').get_attribute("href")

        links.append(link)

# loop breaks here when it paginates through all pages 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'links' : links})
```

depending on your IDE you can print your rows in a number of ways,

simple call `print(df2)` or if you truly want to iterate over your dataframe

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using your code, when I paginate to the next page it overwrites the previous page values.

Answer (score 0):

`Iterrows` would do it.

```
For ind, row in df_links.iterrows():
    df2.loc[len(df2), :] = row
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would I need to change the way the print code is written? I ran the script with your code and it errors "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'link'"